# how to use webkit scrollbar change style and don't resize element

Tags: html, css

I use -webkit codes for changing style scrollbar in chrome and I have one problem!!!
my problem is when scrollbar to be Appears my elements move to right While the I want when scrollbar to be appears my element don't move please guide me about it.

this is my code:

webkit code for scroll:

```
/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}
```

this is my list that get scroll:

```
<ul id="friend-list">
    <li class="on" id="1" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="state">
                <div class="friend-img"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name">
                    <span>Amirhossein</span>
                </div>
                <div class="friend-state"><span class="stat">Online Now</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-profile"></div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="on" id="2" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="state">
                <div class="friend-img"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name">
                    <span>Mohammad</span>
                </div>
                <div class="friend-state"><span class="stat">Online Now</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-profile"></div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="bs" id="3" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="state">
                <div class="friend-img"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name">
                    <span>Mohammad Javad</span>
                </div>
                <div class="friend-state"><span class="stat">Busy Now</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-profile"></div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="bs" id="4" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="state">
                <div class="friend-img"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name">
                    <span>Hamidreza</span>
                </div>
                <div class="friend-state"><span class="stat">Busy Now</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-profile"></div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="bs" id="5" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="state">
                <div class="friend-img"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name">
                    <span>Saeid</span>
                </div>
                <div class="friend-state"><span class="stat">Busy Now</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-profile"></div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="of" id="6" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="state">
                <div class="friend-img"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name">
                    <span>Mehdi</span>
                </div>
                <div class="friend-state"><span class="stat">Offline Now</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-profile"></div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="of" id="7" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="state">
                <div class="friend-img"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name">
                    <span>Mehdi</span>
                </div>
                <div class="friend-state"><span class="stat">Offline Now</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-profile"></div>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li class="of" id="8" conversation="">
        <button class="conver-link">
            <div class="state">
                <div class="friend-img"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-detail">
                <div class="friend-name">
                    <span>Mehdi</span>
                </div>
                <div class="friend-state"><span class="stat">Offline Now</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="friend-profile"></div>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Post some relevant code?

Comment: Post a jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the problem. What you posted would not even scroll, because it's just a `<ul>`.

Comment: i tried the same cod in jsfiddle and couldnt replicate the issue..nothing moved towards the right